# jQuery Input Validation

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

I am trying to make sure my inputs aren't empty on my form. I am using jQuery to check the inputs, but it isn't checking the inputs. The submit button allows it to go through:

```
<form id="preenrollment-airlines" name="preenrollment-airlines" class="tn-form-conversion" method="post" action="#" onSubmit="return(validate());">
<div class="form-col">
    <input id="firstName" name="firstName" onFocus="if (this.value=='firstName') this.value = ''" type="text" placeholder="First name*">
</div>
<div class="form-col">
    <input id="lastName" type="text" name="lastName" onfocus="if (this.value=='lastName') this.value = ''" type="text" placeholder="Last name*" />
</div>
<div class="form-col">
    <input id="addr" type="text" name="address" onfocus="if (this.value=='address') this.value = ''" type="text" placeholder="Address*" />
</div>
<div class="form-col">
    <input id="city" type="text" name="city" onfocus="if (this.value=='city') this.value = ''" type="text" placeholder="City*" />
</div>
<div class="form-col">
    <input id="zip" type="text" name="postalCode" onfocus="if (this.value=='postalCode') this.value = ''" type="text" placeholder="Postal Code*" />
</div>
<div class="form-col">
    <input id="dm" type="text" name="dm" onfocus="if (this.value=='dm') this.value = ''" type="text" placeholder="DM # * (Bottom left corner of your letter)" id="dm" />
</div>
<div class="form-col">
    <input id="email" type="text" name="email" onfocus="if (this.value=='email') this.value = ''" type="text" placeholder="Email*" />
</div>
<div class="form-col">
    <input type="text" name="digits" onfocus="if (this.value=='digits') this.value = ''" type="text" placeholder="Last 4 digits of current BMO AIR MILES World credit card*" id="digits" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<input type="hidden" name="formName" id="formName_id" value="preenrollment-airlines" />
<div style="clear: both;">
    <br />
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <input id="submit" style="margin-top: 25px;" class="primary button" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript I have so far:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#preenrollment-airlines input').blur(function () {
            if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
                $(this).parents('input').addClass('warning');
            }
        });
    });
```

I'm not sure where to go from here. I can't use any plugins to do the validation, so I need to check if the inputs are blank and then I can add a class to it.

Comment: Have you tried without the `.parents('input')`? You've already selected `input` so you won't have any ancestors of type `input`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to capture the Submit event in order to prevent the form from sending. In this function you can check to ensure the inputs are all valid.

For more on the submit event and how to capture it using jQuery,
[view the docs here](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)